# QFileSystemModel sorting DirsFirst

Tags: qt, sorting, qfilesystemmodel

How do you do to sort a QFileSystemModel with QDir::DirsFirst like in QDirModel?
The QFileSystemModel does not have a `setSorting` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't (in Qt4).

The default sort order (by the "name" column), or sorting by size behaves like `QDir::DirsFirst` (or `DirsLast` if in reverse order for ), but sorting by time or type doesn't treat directories differently from ordinary files.

The `QFileSystemModel` doesn't expose an API for changing the sort order, and I don't see any opportunity for influencing it in the `QFileSystemModel` code.

(I don't see anything in the current Qt5 docs to indicate that this has changed, but those aren't final and I haven't looked very closely.)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up sorting by the size column.

Comment: The canonical way of doing it would be to add a proxy model that sorts it the way you want.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe somebody will need this. I have implemented directories first sorting using QSortFilterProxyModel for QFileSystemModel as Kuba Ober mention in comment.
Might be not perfect yet, but still right direction.

```
bool MySortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const
{
    // If sorting by file names column
    if (sortColumn() == 0) {
        QFileSystemModel *fsm = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());
        bool asc = sortOrder() == Qt::AscendingOrder ? true : false;

        QFileInfo leftFileInfo  = fsm->fileInfo(left);
        QFileInfo rightFileInfo = fsm->fileInfo(right);


        // If DotAndDot move in the beginning
        if (sourceModel()->data(left).toString() == "..")
            return asc;
        if (sourceModel()->data(right).toString() == "..")
            return !asc;

        // Move dirs upper
        if (!leftFileInfo.isDir() && rightFileInfo.isDir()) {
            return !asc;
        }
        if (leftFileInfo.isDir() && !rightFileInfo.isDir()) {
            return asc;
        }
    }

    return QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(left, right);
}
```